Changing the Image Content
I develop a Quran App and I want when the user slides the screen to the right or the left then
next picture or the next picture appear in the content
but i have a lot of pictures in the app
I try to work with array and files to storage the pictures but it doesn't work
I don't know how to slide the screen to the right and the left

If you are developing using the classic View system, use ViewPager. If you are developing using Jetpack Compose, use HorizontalPager().
